# Kendo UI grid not calling the webservice

Tags: kendo-ui

I am new to Kendo UI, I have a grid which I populate from a asmx webservice in JSON format, it displays the data fine. I have enabled editing, but when I click the update button nothing happens, I am not getting to the breakpoint in my webmethod.

Here is the relevant code snipets.
Thanks

```
//references
    <link href="Content/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.common.min.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.default.min.css" rel="Stylesheet" />

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.web.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


//Data Model Classes
    [Serializable]
    public class Make
    {
        public int PhoneMakeID { get; set; }
        public string PhoneMakeDesc { get; set; }
        public string BillingDesc { get; set; }
    }


//Web Methods
    //Phone Make Get that populates the grid, works 100%     
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public List<Make> GetPhoneMakes(string Active, string OfferTypeID, string TrackMonthID, string NetworkID)
        {
            DataTable dtPhoneMakes = new DataTable();

            Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("PricingConnection");
            DbCommand dbCommand = null;
            dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("uspPS_PhoneMake_Get");
            db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@OfferTypeID", DbType.String, OfferTypeID);
            db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@TrackMonthID", DbType.String, TrackMonthID);
            db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@NetworkID", DbType.String, NetworkID);
            db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@Active", DbType.String, Active);

            dtPhoneMakes = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand).Tables[0];

            List<Make> ml = new List<Make>();
            Make m;

            foreach (DataRow dr in dtPhoneMakes.Rows)
            {
                m = new Make();
                m.PhoneMakeID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["PhoneMakeID"].ToString());
                m.PhoneMakeDesc = dr["PhoneMakeDesc"].ToString();
                m.BillingDesc = dr["BillingDesc"].ToString();

                ml.Add(m);
            }

            return ml;
        }


 //Phone Make Update, not getting to here
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public void UpdatePhoneMakes(string PhoneMakeID, string PhoneMakeDesc, string BillingDesc)
        {
            Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("PricingConnection");
            DbCommand dbCommand = null;
            dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("uspPS_PhoneMake_Update");
            db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@PhoneMakeID", DbType.String, PhoneMakeID);
            db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@PhoneMakeDesc", DbType.String, PhoneMakeDesc);
            db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@BillingDesc", DbType.String, BillingDesc);

            db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand);

        }

//Transports
            var transpPhoneMake = {
                read: function (options) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "webmethods/phones.asmx/GetPhoneMakes",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: jdPhoneMake,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (msg) {

                            options.success(msg);
                        }
                    });
                },
                update: function (options) {
                    url: "webmethods/phones.asmx/UpdatePhoneMakes/";
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8";                    
                    type: "POST";  
                },
                parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
                    if (operation != "read") {                             
                        return JSON.stringify({ products: data.models })
                    }
                    else {                           
                        data = $.extend({ sort: null, filter: null }, data);
                        return JSON.stringify(data);
                    }
                }
            };


 //DataSources
            var dsPhoneMake = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: transpPhoneMake,
                schema:
                {
                    data: "d",
                    total: "d.length",
                    model:
                    {
                        id: "PhoneMakeID",
                        fields:
                        {
                            PhoneMakeID: { type: "string", editable: false, nullable: true },
                            PhoneMakeDesc: { type: "string", editable: true },
                            BillingDesc: { type: "string", editable: true }
                        }
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 10,
                sort:
                {
                    field: "PhoneMakeDesc",
                    dir: "asc"
                }
            });


//Grids
                var gridPhoneMakes = $("#gridPhoneMakes").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: dsPhoneMake,
                    columns:
                        [
                            { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "175px" },
                            {
                                field: "PhoneMakeID",
                                title: "Make ID",
                                filterable: false,
                                editable: false,
                                width: 75
                            },
                            {
                                field: "PhoneMakeDesc",
                                title: "Make Description",
                                editable: true
                            },
                            {
                                field: "BillingDesc",
                                title: "Make Code",
                                editable: true
                            }
                        ],
                    toolbar: kendo.template($("#tmplPhoneMakeToolbar").html()),
                    selectable: "row",
                    sortable: true,
                    groupable: true,
                    pageable: true,
                    filterable: true,
                    autoBind: false,
                    editable: "inline",
                    batch: false
                });
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `transport` definition says:

```
update: function (options) {
    url: "webmethods/phones.asmx/UpdatePhoneMakes/";
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8";                    
    type: "POST";  
},
```

When you are actually not defining a function. It should be something like:

```
update: {
    url: "webmethods/phones.asmx/UpdatePhoneMakes/",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    type: "POST",
},
```

**But** all `transport` definitions must be consistent (Excerpt from KendoUI documentation)

> Note: transport methods should be consistent - create, update and
>   destroy should be specified as functions too

(Thanks @LindsySimon for the remark)

You should do as you did for `read`:

```
read: function (options) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "webmethods/phones.asmx/UpdatePhoneMakes/",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (result) {
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I believe that if you use a function on one transport method, you must use a function for *all* methods.

Comment: I'm not the OP - I was just pointing out that I don't think your second example would work for him, since `read` is already defined as a function.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question and I think that you were wondering about why I thought that the original was wrong. I edit my post and +1 for you. Thanks!